# trouble understanding the increment in this for loop

Tags: c++, for-loop

I made my own for loop thinking I'd know the answer lol clearly I don't. I'm trying to better understand for loops, and while loops etc. So I'm practicing.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int I;
    for ( I = 1 ; I<11 ; I += 3)
        cout << ++I << "," << flush;
    cout << endl;    
}
```

now what I thought the output would be was 1 incremented to 2 and then added to 3
so `I = 1, ++I`, `2+3 = 5`
then `I= 5, ++I`, `6+3 = 9`

so following that output would be 5, 9, before terminating.

but when i compiled it in Visual Studio 2010, the out put i got was 2, 6, 10

I'm thinking it's being incremented first to 2, then incremented again to 3 then added to 3, then 6 incremented to 7, and then added to 3 to get 10.

But that doesn't make sense to me as why the 2 wouldn't be added to the 3 first.

thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Think of

```
for ( I = 1 ; I<11 ; I += 3)
   cout << ++I << "," << flush;
```

as

```
for ( I = 1 ; I<11 ; )
{
    cout << ++I << "," << flush;
    I += 3;
}
```

The `++I` is a pre-increment, so starting off with `I = 1` means you get a `cout << 2` and then `I += 3` which gives you `5`, then on to the next iteration.

(Note that the `5` is pre-incremented to `6` which is then printed during this next iteration)

Comment: oh wow that makes 100% perfect sense. I didn't even think of looking at it like that. so if it was I++ i would have gotten a cout << 1 and so on, right?

Comment: @Umeed best to try it out (but yes)

Answer (score 3):

The `++I` is a pre-increment operator, so first it performs an increment and then returns the value, so you programs runs like this:
1) I = 1, pre-increment, so I=2, print I => **2**, then I+=3 = 5 
2) I = 5, pre-increment, so I=6, print I => **6**, then I+=3 = 9 
3) I = 9, pre-increment, so I=10, print I => **10**, then I+=3 = 13 
4) I = 13, terminate.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is clearer if you view it like this. Your for loop is equivalent to:

```c++
{
    int I = 1;
    while (I < 11)
    {
        ++I;
        out << I << "," << flush;
        I += 3;
    }
}
```

Note that the pre-increment returns the current value of `I` (the value after the increment).